# Boot time text(Boot log text) low resolution and graphic

Tags: boot, graphics, display-resolution

I'm new to linux, I just installed Kubuntu and I've noticed for Kubuntu the boot time text is in very low resolution and graphic mode.
I've installed some other distros like manjaro, solus, mint, pop os, arcolinux and so.
some of these had very clear, polished and nice text log in boot time and also very good graphical representation when loged in to the gui (ssdm, gdm,...).
but some of them still look blurry and pixeled like very old graphical interfaces.
my machine is Acer aspire-e5-475g with dual graphic cards, an onboard intel and an additional nvidia 940mx. even when I installed the Nvidia's driver as well, the graphical representation is not very good.
is it possible that some distros have driver support for that intel chipset and some other have not?
what is the problem here?

Kubuntu is latest version 22.04
and as comments are pointing to `grub` I don't think it's related to the grub, because some distros don't use grub as solus or arch linux that I used with systemd-boot.
the text I mentioned is not the grub menu, its the long wall text on boot time, that shows whtas going on, which module is loading and so on.

Comment: No, it's not about the Intel driver that all distro have because open-source. The fact is many distros, some you mentioned, always had fancy Grub while Ubuntu a more plain one.

Comment: So what is the Kubuntu version?

Comment: How `grub` appears can vary on version of grub (*you gave no release details*), video card in use & more.  eg. I can boot Lubuntu ISOs and how they look will vary on box booted, plus release used.. `grub` and `sddm` are configurable, beyond what is provided, as default setup is minimal (*I'm using Lubuntu as example only because it's what I know best; same applies with Kubuntu/Xubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Ubuntu etc, and `sddm` config is far easier to modify with Kubuntu compared to Lubuntu*)

Comment: tnx guys, I edited the question to add more details

Comment: Ubuntu now offers to install correct nVidia driver as part of install. So have you installed more than one nVidia driver, that leads to conflicts. First is it installed? `dkms status` & `sudo lshw -c display` If multiple drivers causing conflicts: `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` & then install correct one: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: dkms is not installed at all(no auto-install as part of kubuntu installation nor installed by me). I checked the box for install 3'rd party drivers when I was installing the iso but it installed nvidia 510, then I removed that and used ubuntu-drivers autoinstall to install nvidia 515. using nvidia settings now I can switch to use intel or nvidia